# Get dictionary key object properties

Tags: c#, class, object

I am trying to retrieve a dictionary's key property, as the key is a class. How do you do it? Here is the class that I use:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Sku { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
    } 
}
```

I am trying to retrieve a property of it for example `Name`:

```
Dictionary<Item,double> myDictionary = new Dictionary<Item,double>();
Item item = new Item { Sku = 123, Name = "myItem" };
myDictionary.Add(item,10.5);
```

So now for example how from this dictionary I would retrieve the item's `Name` or `Sku`, or any other property if it would have them?

Comment: Use the get method to retrieve the names!

Comment: Are you sure you want the key to be a class? Why?

Comment: what exactly you wanna do ..

Comment: pass this dictonary to another class so it can do its work.

Comment: Itprobably would be more reasonable to use the Item class a value not as a key?

Comment: @MrEnergy Are you sure that you want a dictionary then and not just a regular list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` if you want to use your class as key of a `Dictionary`, otherwise you're comparing references.

Here's an example where `Equals` checks if two items have the same `Name`.

```
public class Item
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        Item i2 = obj as Item;
        if(i2 == null) return false;
        return StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Equals(Name, i2.Name);
    }
    // rest of class  ...
}
```

But the question is not clear. You use a dictionary to lookup elements by the key. So you want to find the value by providing the key. That means you have already a key which makes your question pointless.

However, you can loop a dictionary even if it's not made for this:

```
foreach(var kv in mydictronary)
{
     Item i = kv.Key;
    // now you have all properties of it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve your item, you need to use the same item (the same reference). You can do it in such way:

```
var myDouble = myDictonary[item];
```

When you use object as a key in a directory, its hash code is use to add/retrieve item from it - you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want use a string to retrieve items, then you should use strings as a key in you dictionary:

```
Dictonary<string,double> mydictronary = new Dictonary<string,double>();
```

Comment: this will retrieve him the value which is double

Comment: hmm, then probably I don't understand the question.

Comment: as far as i understand mr.energy wants to use the properties of the key of the dictionary and not the value

Comment: ok, but then I probably suggest defining this dictionary in a way that suits his needs - as I mentioned maybe the key of the dictionary should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate of the dictionary like this:

`foreach(var keyValuePair in myDictionary)
{
kvp.Key.
}`

then youll get all of the properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq:

```
var item = myDictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Name == "myItem");
var item = myDictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Sku == 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three options.

1. You can use the same instance of the class to index, as in `var x = myDictionary[item]`.
2. You can implementa customer comparer (something that implements `IEqualityComparer<Item>`), and pass that in to the constructor of your dictionary. For details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. You can implement `IEquatable<Item>` on your `Item` class. For details see [IEquatable on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can access keys from the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

From MSDN

```
// To get the keys alone, use the Keys property.
Dictionary<string, string>.KeyCollection keyColl = openWith.Keys;

// The elements of the KeyCollection are strongly typed 
// with the type that was specified for dictionary keys.
Console.WriteLine();
foreach( string s in keyColl )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}", s);
}
```